# Input 0 of layer "dense3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4096,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am pretty new to keras and machine learning, but my code is not working and I am pretty sure it is because of my model.  I am trying to train my model with a csv file that has my images all flattened into one row.  Essentially, each row of data is one image.  However, this error message keeps popping up

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).

```
Input 0 of layer "dense3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4096,)

Call arguments received by layer "sequential" (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(4096,), dtype=uint8)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

I have looked online and tried a lot of things, but I am new, so I do not completely understand everything.  The image is 64x64, so I assumed that the columns were the input size.... so set the input size equal to 64*64 and also changed the predict batch size to be 64*64 that way it matches (since I am getting the real-time flattened image to be predicted).  It solved the problem for the first layer (the input layer), but now the dense layers after are not working.  I also have the image label at the first index of every row on the csv file.

```
def modelTraining():
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(4096,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name = "dense2"), )
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name = "dense3", ))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

#Get our training image data
trainingImageMatrix = []
trainingLabelsArray = []
temp = 0
with open(r'C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\signLanguage\testOpenCV\training.csv', 'r', newline='') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        temp+=1
        imageDataToAdd = np.zeros(4096)
        for i in range (1, 4097):
            imageDataToAdd[i - 1] = row[i]
        trainingLabelsArray.append(int(row[0])) #need to get the first index of every row
        trainingImageMatrix.append(imageDataToAdd)
        print("reading row: "+str(temp))
        #if temp >=10:
            #break
    trainingImageMatrix = np.array(trainingImageMatrix)
    trainingLabelsArray = np.array(trainingLabelsArray)
model.fit(trainingImageMatrix, trainingLabelsArray, epochs = 20, batch_size = 4096)
return model
```

```
model.predict(grayFrame.flatten(), batch_size = 4096)
```

this line is in another part of my code, but this is the predict I am using atm.

Would appreciate some help and clarification on how to specify the size and how the layers should be customized for my task.

[each row has the 0th index as a label and the rest is 64*64 worth of pixel brightness ---- CSV FILE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWbeb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/zikazika/tutorial-deep-learning-for-absolute-beginners/data) dataset and converted the npy file to csv and replicated the issue. grayFrame.flatten() gives the output of 1 dimension. Adding an extra dimension will solve the error. Replace the following line

```
model.predict(grayFrame.flatten(), batch_size = 4096)
```

with the line below

```
model.predict(tf.expand_dims(grayFrame.flatten(),axis=0), batch_size = 4096)
```

Please find the sample code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/fbf9f67f9cab8d4d5a92f4b3b40ba206/untitled130.ipynb). Thank you!